# Is this a well-defined norm on the space of linear maps?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I'm reading linear maps in my lecture note:

> [image]

In *Ex 1.2.2*, we are required to prove that $||| \cdot |||$ is indeed a norm on $L(E,F)$.

I'm struggling for two hours to prove that $\{||f(x)||_{F} \mid ||x||_{E}=1\}$ is bounded from above but to no avail. If $\{||f(x)||_{F} \mid ||x||_{E}=1\}$ is not bounded from above, $\sup _{\|x\|_{E}=1}\|f(x)\|_{F}$ is not finite and such $||| \cdot |||$ is not a function from $L(E,F)$ to $\mathbb R$.

**My question:** Is the exercise correctly written or I miss something?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is false in general, that is, it can happen that $\left\{\bigl\lVert f(x)\bigr\rVert\,\middle|\,\lVert x\rVert=1\right\}$ is unbounded. You have to assume that $f$ is continuous. This will automatically hold if $\dim E<\infty$.

Comment: Assume that $\dim E = n$ and $\{e_1,...,e_n\}$ is a basis of $E$. Then $x =\sum \lambda_i e_i$ and thus $||f(x)||_F =||f(\sum \lambda_i e_i)||_{F} = ||\sum \lambda_i f(e_i)||_F \le \sum |\lambda_i| \cdot ||f(e_i)||_F$. For $||x||_E=1$, I'm unable to prove that $\sum |\lambda_i| \cdot ||f(e_i)||_F$ is bounded from above. Please shed me some light!

Comment: It is easy to prove what you want to prove if$$\lVert\lambda_1e_1+\cdots+\lambda_ne_n\rVert=\lvert\lambda_1\rvert+\cdots+\lvert\lambda_n\rvert.$$And then you can use the fact that, in a finite-dimensional real vector space, all norms are equivalent.

Comment: Ah I got it, thank you so much!